# Accessing the properties of component A in component B?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-components

I can't use `@Input`, because the two components are far apart in the components tree.

Using a service looks like the only option, but it seems very overkill to have a service that is essentially a duplicate of all component's A properties. Every time I set a property in A, I would also need to set it in the service so that B has access to it. Doesn't seem very efficient.

Isn't there a way to inject the instance of component A in component B? Note that A isn't a parent/child of B.

Cheers!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm aware of services, please read my question.

Comment: You can bind to a property of a service

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You mean using an Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to a property of a service

```ts
@Component({
  ...
  template: <div>{{myService.someProp}}</div>
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService:MyService){}
}
```

then you don't need to duplicate.

Comment: The duplicating doesn't occur when getting the property, it occurs when setting it. To set it, you need to set it in the component + in the service.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Why would you need to set it on the component. Three is no property on the component to be set.

Comment: Oh right. So you're suggesting to only set the property in the service. Didn't think about that.

Comment: That's a good answer! I'm wondering how much of a good or bad practice this is.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the use case. It's not considered too good practice but as you say, sometimes observables might be overkill. A big advantage of of observables is that they push-notify about changes and Angular doesn't have to do change detection checks. So if you have a complex application with many such properties you might notice it in the performance.

Comment: My concern is not so much about setting the property to the service vs using a push-notify pattern, but rather about not setting anything to the component. I know my goal was to avoid duplication, which is the reason why you suggested to only set the property on the service, but it seems weird that the component has no property. Or perhaps I'm going through a paradigm shift where all components should have a service for the actual data/model and the only properties that should be set on the components are those that are exclusively related to the design/view/animation/etc.

Comment: Actually that is the good part of this pattern. It's a good idea to have the components as simple as possible and specialized in rendering the model and move the model and the business logic out of components to services.
This makes code easier to test and components easier to reuse.